# Finding $(\alpha - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta)$ if they are roots of given quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

### If $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of the equation $x^2 + px - q = 0$. $\gamma , \delta$ are roots of equation $x^2 + px -r$, then find the value of $(\alpha - \gamma )(\alpha - \delta)$.

**Answer - $q-r$**

---

My try -

$\alpha + \beta= -p$ and $\alpha \beta = -q$

similarly,

$\gamma + \delta = -p$ and $\gamma \delta = -r$

Then to we've to find:

$(\alpha - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta) = \alpha^2 - \alpha \delta - \alpha \gamma + \gamma \delta $ out of which only $\gamma \delta$ is known, then how to find the rest?

Also, when noticed carefully about the question, we find that question is $(\alpha - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta)$ which doesn't have $\beta$ in its product, which makes the question more confusing.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Where is $\beta$ in your product?

Comment: Isn't it $$(\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\delta)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner which product? Can you clarify a bit please?

Comment: I have written is above and you can call me Sonnhard.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, sir, if $\beta$ had been given in the equation, then I'd have solved the question, I again checked the question but didn't found any &\beta&

Comment: Hm, i'm wondering, let me see.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks sir for your attention!

Comment: See my solution below, it is as i sayed, $$(\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\delta)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, sir, I doubted the correctness of the question asked, apologies for wrong question due to misprint in question

Comment: Well, something's a misprint. Either the question or the given answer.

Comment: @Matt Should I remove the question or edit it saying that there must be misprint somewhere?

Comment: You might as well leave the question, now. Pick whichever answer you like the most and accept that as your answer by clicking the tick, and then let the question stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\alpha + \beta = \gamma + \delta \implies \beta = \gamma + \delta - \alpha$

Now, $(\alpha - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta) = \alpha^2 - \alpha \delta - \alpha \gamma + \gamma \delta =  \alpha(\alpha - \delta - \gamma) + \gamma\delta = \alpha(-\beta) +\gamma\delta = \gamma\delta - \alpha\beta $

$= -r + q$

Comment: Seems like that there's misprint in textbook

Comment: $(\alpha - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta) = 0$ iff there is a solution satifying both equations, which can only happen if q=r.  Hence answer must be k(q-r) for some k.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at here @dm63

Comment: @Matt, I was looking at the possibility that $(\alpha-\gamma)(\alpha-\delta)=0$ This happens if and only if either $\alpha = \gamma$ or $\alpha= \delta$, which means that the equations have a common solution.  Hence, we attempt to solve them simultaneously.  Subtracting them gives q=r.  Hence $(\alpha-\gamma)(\alpha-\delta)=0$ if and only if q=r, from which I concluded that $(\alpha-\gamma)(\alpha-\delta)=k(q-r)$ for some k.  This is not needed , since the question has already been answered, but I though it might be interesting.  I could not find a way of deducing k=-1 to complete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We get by solving the quadratic
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{p}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}+q}$$
and

$$x_{3,4}=-\frac{p}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}+r}$$
so we get

$$(\alpha-\gamma)(\beta-\delta)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}+q}-\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}+r}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}+q}+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}+r}\right)=\frac{p^2}{4}+q-\frac{p^2}{4}-r=q-r$$ as you stated.

Comment: Thanks for Clarification, the question is misprinted in the textbook

Answer (score 1):

By the given: $$(\alpha-\gamma)(\alpha-\delta)=\alpha^2+p\alpha-r=q-r.$$

Comment: Seems like misprint in my textbook answer, apologies

Comment: @Abhas Kumar Sinha I did not see your answer. I also think so.

Comment: Should I edit the question or add details the the question might be incorrect?

Comment: I think the idea of the solution  would be the same idea.

Comment: which solution?

Comment: I mean my solution of the problem.

Comment: I think I should edit the question, whereas your answer is correct unlike question

Comment: OK. You can fix.

Comment: Well, I must ask you, how do you solve questions so quickly? :P You did a similar question earlier or what?

Comment: I just like to solve math problems. :)

Comment: What you solved in second would have taken millions of rebirths for me XD

Comment: Well do you plan your strategy on the spot or try to solve the puzzle after each step?

Comment: I just used the definition of an equation root.